# How to add HTML markup programmatically in a Ruby on Rails view?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to return a formatted error message in the ActiveControler flash hash.  This is rendered in my layout as:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    #<%= content_tag :p, msg, class: "flash #{name}" %>
<% end %>
```

When the msg = 'Bob' I get:

```
<p class="flash error">Bob</p>
```

Which displays as:

```
Bob
```

When the msg = '

1. Bob

' I get:

```
<p class="flash error">"<ol><li>Bob</li></ol>"</p>
```

Which displays as:

```
<ol><li>Bob</li></ol>
```

What I want is to have it displayed as an ordered list of error messages.

I have also tried changing out the content_tag helper for straight hand coded markup and that doesn't change anything.  I also tried replacing "<" and ">" with < and >.  Of course that didn't help either.  I know I can give up on this and write a custom error reporting page that behaves exactly as I want, but I was trying to do this in a simpler way.

Comment: I'm not sure on this but try '<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :p, msg.html_safe, class: "flash #{name}" %>
<% end %>'

Comment: @AnezioCampos, looks correct, but going a step further to make it an ordered list: `<ol> <% flash.each do |name, msg| %> <%= content_tag :li, msg.html_safe, class: "flash #{name}" %> <% end %></ol>`

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're using content tag right in the view when a regular tag works fine? Content tag is good for helper methods, so you can easily create html inside ruby code. Here's how i would do it in the view:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
<ol>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <li class="flash #{name}"><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not doing it that way because this code is in my layout and most flash messages are a single line.

Answer (score 0):

[Anezio Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438190/anezio-campos) suggests html_safe.  After much research I chose to use sanitize with a white list of allowed tags instead.  However, I still had a frustrating problem.

This code is being presented to the browser as HTML5.  The problem appears in Chrome which is our projects only supported browser.  I know that's a bad idea, but it's not my decision.  Anyway if you look at the the [W3 HTML Language Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) it says the ending paragraph tag is optional.  Chrome placed my markup outside of the paragraph I was using to style the block!

So the final piece of the puzzle was to change from a paragraph tag to a div tag.

The result looks like:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <% next if name.blank? || msg.blank? %>
    <div class="flash <%= name %>">
      <%= sanitize(msg, tags: %w(ol li)) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```